# Inject touch screen events， Android 5.0 ， dev/input/eventX

Tags: android, touch

I am working on some program that will need to inject touch screen events to the phone within the program, i am using the opensource lib https://code.google.com/p/android-event-injector/ to manually send touch screen events on rooted Android devices, through direct injection of codes in dev/input/event3,  but everything stops working when I updated the phone to Android 5.0 and can't event scan any input devices files under dev/input/, anyone has any idea to work this around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full SELinux enforcement introduced in Lollipop causes this. One workaround is to invoke "setenforce Permissive" as root.

Edit: If you have SuperSU installed on the device, the following policy will also grant access to /dev/input without having to drop SELinux to permissive mode.

```
supolicy --live "allow appdomain input_device dir { ioctl read getattr search open }" "allow appdomain input_device chr_file { ioctl read write getattr lock append open }"
```

Comment: @Irwin thanks for your answer, is there any workaround to use instrumentation for touch simulation on Lollipop? it doesn't work too. Thanks.

Comment: @DorochiOkamoto how did you run the command? I've placed it in runtime in android app code, and it didn't allow injecting touches. Please help me, how did you get this to work?